# Volume of region example

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

What's the easier aproach to calculate the volume of the following region:

$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: 0\leq y \wedge x+y\leq 1 \wedge x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1 \}$$

The way I did this will sound really dumb, and I got a really complicated integral so solve, which is not the idea of the exercise.

I restricted my problem to $z \geq 0$, there is symmetry. Then I wanted to study the region where $0\leq z \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ in which the plane defined by $x+y \leq 1$ intersects the level curves $x^2+y^2= 1 - z^2_0$ in two points.

From here i was able to define the area define the "area of the region" in $z_0$. Which if I didn't get it wrong, it is given for a fixed $z$: $\arctan(-1+\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-2z^2}}{z^2}) + \frac{\sqrt{4-8z^2}}{4}$

Integrating this doesn't sound like the intention of the exercise. So any solution or hint would be helpful

Comment: Hint : You are trying to compute the volume of a subset of a unit sphere ($x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leqslant 1$). This subset is defined by the two constraints $ y \geqslant 0$ and $x+y\leqslant 1$. Those constraints cut out portions of the sphere whose volume is not that hard to compute.

Comment: The third condition gives us a sphere. y=0 chops the sphere in half. x+y=1 is a plane. You may be able to work out the bit chopped off by the plane as the difference between a cone and a 3D segment (not sure what that is called - something to do with steradians).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x+y \leq 1, y \geq 0, x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$,

Bounds of $z$ is defined by the sphere so $ - \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \leq z \leq - \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

Lower bounds of $x$ is sphere and upper bound is plane $x + y \leq 1$.

So, $ - \sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x \leq 1-y$

Finally, bounds of $y$ is $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

So integral to find volume is

$\displaystyle V = \int_0^1 \int_{- \sqrt{1-y^2}}^{1-y} 2 \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} \ dx \ dy$

Another approach is to rotate coordinate system clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ around z-axis and use cylindrical coordinates.

$x = r \cos (\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}), y = r \sin (\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}), r^2 + z^2 \leq 1$

$x + y \leq 1 \implies \sqrt2 \ r \sin\theta \leq 1$

So volume of the region is given by,

$\displaystyle V = \int_{3\pi/4}^{5\pi/4} \int_0^1 2 r \sqrt{1-r^2} \ dr \ d\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \int_0^{\csc\theta / \sqrt2} 2 r \sqrt{1-r^2} \ dr \ d\theta$

$ = \displaystyle \frac{5 \pi}{6 \sqrt2}$